# page not found Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.10 (Win32)

Tags: php, wordpress

hii my wordpress home page is working properly when i click links i got an error like this  "Object not found!  The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.  If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15  " can you help me this to solve

Comment: Is it in a sub-directory?

Comment: Would be because mod_rewrite problem also CLick these: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-errors-after-install
http://support.hostgator.in/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/404-errors-after-clicking-wordpress-links

Comment: mr.Daren , ma home page is working but am click any link or go to wp-admin it w'l show error page not found

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and realized that when you upgrade to Apache 2.4 the rewrite_module is commented out. Comment out line 168 in your httpd.conf file and everything should be working again.

[image]